# How to prevent short strings from being added to a set

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to parse some emails from a text file. Based on https://gist.github.com/dideler/5219706 , I have:

```
def getEmails(freeText):

    r = re.compile(("([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`"
                        "{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|"
                        "\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))

    results = r.findall(freeText)
    myset = set() # USING A SET AVOIDS DUPLICATES
    for x in results:
        if len(x)>2:
            myset.add(str(x))

    return myset
```

This works pretty well, but I'm getting a set returned that looks like:

```
"('myname@abc.org', '@', '.')
```

I added the line:

```
if len(x)>2:
```

with the hope that this would eliminate single character results from the returned set, but as you can see its not working. Why not? How can I fix this to get only true emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check for lengths. Turn in-between two capturing groups into non-capturing groups like below.

```
([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*(?:@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.|\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)
                                                                   ^                                              ^
                                                                   |                                              |
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xJ6dN7/2)

Comment: Awsome Avinash, That works! I'm not experienced with regex, would you mind explaining what you've done? Best  - Bill

Comment: `re.findall` gives first preference to the groups . If no capturing groups are found then only it would print the matches. You original regex contains three capturing groups. The one which captures the whole email address  and the another captures the dot and then the other captures the `@` symbol. So you get three parts. I just turn capturing groups which captures `@` and dot to non-capturing group. So finally we have a single capturing group. Now findall prints the contents which was present in that single group.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the program in the link you sent (line 28), you can see that they are only using the first element of the tuple of the results from the regex.

So you probably want to change this:

```
for x in results:
    if len(x)>2:
        myset.add(str(x))
```

into:

```
for x in results:        
    if len(x[0])>2:
        myset.add(x[0])
```

...or just change the regex